Referencing a foreign key field attached to another model in a Django filter
I have a Profile model which is related to the Django User model via a 1:1 relationship. In the profile model is a field "nickname." I am filtering a table with a foreign key to the User model but want to display the nickname in the filter. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
 
class MyCourse(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
[other stuff]

class MyCourseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    sorted_nicknames = <WHAT GOES HERE?>
    nickname = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=sorted_nicknames, label='Nickname')

